Reorder column of a dataset based on the order of another dataset in R
I have two dataframes in R,
df1 :



Var1
Val1




A
2


B
3


C
4


D
5



and df2 :



Var1
Val2




D
101


C
103


B
17


A
99



i want to reorder data frame df2 , and more specifically to reorder the order of column var2 of df2 based on the order of the column var1 of  df1. Ideally  i want my new data frame to look like this :



var2
Val2




A
99


B
17


C
103


D
101



How can i do this in R  and if it is possible using dplyr functions ?
data :

library(tidyverse)
df1 = tibble(var1 = c("A","B","C","D"),val1 = c(2,3,4,5))%>%
  mutate(var1 = as.factor(var1))
df2 = tibble(var1 = c("D","C","B","A"),val2 = c(101,103,17,99))%>%
  mutate(var1 = as.factor(var1))




Maybe
df2 %>%
    arrange(var1[df1$var1])

or
df2 %>%
    arrange(match(var1, df1$var1))

or
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2) %>%
    select(-val1)

which gives
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  var1   val2
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A        99
2 B        17
3 C       103
4 D       101


Using match().
> df2[order(df1$val1[match(df2$var1, df1$var1)]), ]
  var1 val2
4    A   99
3    B   17
2    C  103
1    D  101


I did a fusion thanks to the function merge from the base package :
join <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="Var1", by.y="Var2")

Here I say that I want merge df1 and df2 using for fusion's column the column Var1 in x (df1) and Var2 in y (df2)
result <- join[c(1, 3)]

Finally, I select the columns I want to keep.

Just FYI, merge is a base function. The dplyr equivalent is their suite of join functions, either inner_join or left_join would work well here.

This possible solution with forcats is close to what you've tried and will handle groups who exists in df2 but not in df1:
(toy data at the end)
library(tidyverse)

# `forcats` approach
new_df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = fct(Var1, levels = unique(c(df1$Var1, Var1)))) %>% 
  arrange(Var1)

The output:
> new_df2
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Var1   Val2
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A        99
2 B        17
3 C       103
4 D       101
5 E        -1
6 F       -10

Toy data with new groups in df2:
# Toy data
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Var1, ~Val1,
  "A",     2,
  "B",     3,
  "C",     4,
  "D",     5)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Var1, ~Val2,
  "E",    -1, # <--
  "D",   101,
  "C",   103,
  "B",    17,
  "A",    99,
  "F",   -10) # <--

Created on 2024-05-19 with reprex v2.1.0
